Proof for conservation of angular momentum in rotating frame of reference
imagine a simple situation such that an object is rotating on a table about a rope as seen in the below figure

now if i pull on the rope from the center , the radius of circular motion of the object decreases so the angular velocity must increase due to conservation of linear momentum.
my doubt is , if i were to evaluate the situation in rotating frame of reference which was rotating along the ball
the increase in tension resulting only a increase force in radial direction
so what causes my angular velocity to increase then?
(since there is no force in the tangential direction)


since there is no force in the tangential direction

In the rotating reference frame, the Coriolis force $\vec{F}_\text{cor} = 2 m \vec{v} \times \vec{\Omega}$ on an object moving inwards acts in the tangential direction.  Specifically, if $\vec{v} = - v \hat{r}$, we have
$$
\vec{F}_\text{cor} = 2 m (-v \hat{r}) \times (\Omega \hat{z}) = 2 m v \Omega \hat{\theta}
$$
and so the ball will move in the tangential direction according to a rotating observer.
